# Maximimization problem with quadratic equality constraint

Tags: optimization, discrete-optimization, qcqp

Given this optimization problem,

$Max \quad Q(x)$

$s.t., \quad x \in X$

$\quad \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^2 = k$

where $x_i$ are integers, $x \in X$ is a set of linear inequalities,  k is a parameter, and Q(x) is a quadratic function of x.

I'm interested in knowing if there is an efficient way to solve this problem. Given the fact that the second constraint is in the form of equality, the problem is not convex or conic.

Comment: Can you post an example?

Comment: You should be able to convert this problem into a large-scale integer linear program (with only binary integer variables) as follows: Note that the integer variables $x_i$ are bounded since the equality implies $x_i \in [-\lfloor\sqrt{k}\rfloor, \lfloor\sqrt{k}\rfloor]$. Using this observation, you can replace each integer variable $x_i$ using combinations of (a finite number of) binary variables $y_{ij}$. The objective and constraint can also be linearized using standard techniques for linearizing quadratic functions of binary variables. I'm hoping that someone will post a cleverer answer.

Comment: The [Sequential quadratic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_quadratic_programming) method is a very good algorithm for non-linear problems. There are implementations of the algorithm in most scientific software and would compute very fast depending on the scale of your problem.

Comment: @Hikaru But SQP does not handle integer variables.

Comment: Just thought I'd also point out that your nonlinear equality constraint is essentially a $\ell_2$-norm equality constraint intersected with integrality restrictions, so I'm not sure if an "efficient algorithm" exists.

Comment: @madnessweasley. I actually agree with your first comment. I can replace that constraint with a set of linear equality (McCormick) and model the problem as a large scale MIP. In my model, the quadratic constraint is in fact redundant. The reason why I added it is because it could improve my LP relaxation. In order to linearize this quadratic constraint, I have to add new variables and constraints which may still influence my LP relaxation. Do you have any thought on which models might have better performance: (1) the model without the quadratic constraint or (2) the larger MIQP model.

Comment: @user2512443 I'm not sure, but here are my thoughts (disclaimer: I'm not an integer programming expert by any means, so take the following with a healthy pinch of salt). Adding auxiliary variables and linearizing the problem may make some improvement to the LP relaxation, but I am not sure that it will improve the overall computational performance. Linearizing quadratic terms [has been well-studied](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01589101), and it is known that extreme points of the linearized version may be non-integral (which is not ideal).

Comment: In addition, the LP relaxation of the quadratic equality constraint will contain the convex set $\sum x^2_i \leq k$, so I'm not sure what the benefit of adding the equality constraint is if it is already redundant (as an aside, I'm interested in knowing what your formulation looks like if the equality is redundant - I'm guessing it has something to do with the objective). A better option might be to replace the equality constraint with $\sum x^2_i \leq k$ in the first place and see if it helps improve the convex MIQP solver's performance.

Comment: Finally, if you are set on linearizing the quadratic constraint, you could try an approach [like this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=8D001262A835E7E0C8F87CA00BBD8074?doi=10.1.1.33.94&rep=rep1&type=pdf) that provides an extended formulation to outer-approximate the constraint $\sum x^2_i \leq k$.

Comment: @madnessweasley Thank you. I will look into it.